# Generate a table by column

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would create a table with 10 columns, displaying the values ascending in 5 groups of 50 values for two  in each .

This is  my XML:

```
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4555</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.5</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT> 
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4556</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.6</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT> 
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4557</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.7</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT> 
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4558</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.8</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT> 
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4559</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.9</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT> 
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>4560</ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER>
    <INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>E2686.10</INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
```

Whit this data a would create a particular table by colomn.
This is the output:

---

International |Italia |International |Italia |International |Italia |

---

E2686.5 |4555 | E2686.7 |4557 |  E2686.9  |4559 |
E2686.6 |4556 | E2686.8 |4558 |  E2686.10 |4560 |

until the end of the page, and when the page finish, start from the next column.

Using this XSLT I created it, but I am not able to arrive at the end of page and continue to the next table column, I continue in another page in only one column.

This is my XSLT:

```
<body style="tab-interval:35.4pt">
    <div>
        <table  style="font-size:9pt; border-style:none; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; font-family:Univers Condensed;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
            <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER">
        <xsl:sort select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                    </td>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "*arrive at the end of page*" What page? You seem to be generating HTML. An HTML page has no "end".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I misunderstand the question, but with your current template you're writing the second `<td>` in your `xsl:for-each` loop inside the first `<td>`, which I guess you don't want and is invalid markup. Just change to

```
<xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER">
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to generate the two columns.

**Update:** For the requirement to print a 10 column table to print the first 50 values ascending in the first two columns, then proceeding in columns 3 and 4 for the values from 50 to 100 etc. - an example how this can be achieved for 12 values (for readability).
For the example input I've just added 4 product items to the example XML. Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat"
omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <div>
      <table style="font-size:9pt; border-style:none; border-collapse:collapse;
       vertical-align:top; font-family:Univers Condensed;" border="1" 
       cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td> <p>Internazionale</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Italiano</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Internazionale</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Italiano</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Internazionale</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Italiano</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Internazionale</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Italiano</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Internazionale</p>
          </td>
          <td> <p>Italiano</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER ">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:if test="not(position() >2)">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
              </td>
              <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER ">
              <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=$pos+2">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER ">
              <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=$pos+4">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER ">
              <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=$pos+6">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER ">
              <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=$pos+8">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result HTML:

```
<div>
 <table style="font-size:9pt; border-style:none; border-collapse:collapse;
  vertical-align:top; font-family:Univers Condensed;" border="1" 
  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
     <td>
        <p>Internazionale</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Italiano</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Internazionale</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Italiano</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Internazionale</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Italiano</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Internazionale</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Italiano</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Internazionale</p>
     </td>
     <td>
        <p>Italiano</p>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>E2686.5</td>
     <td>4555</td>
     <td>E2686.7</td>
     <td>4557</td>
     <td>E2686.9</td>
     <td>4559</td>
     <td>E2686.11</td>
     <td>4561</td>
     <td>E2686.13</td>
     <td>4563</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>E2686.6</td>
     <td>4556</td>
     <td>E2686.8</td>
     <td>4558</td>
     <td>E2686.10</td>
     <td>4560</td>
     <td>E2686.12</td>
     <td>4562</td>
     <td>E2686.14</td>
     <td>4564</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

To work for the groups of 50 values, you would just have to adjust the values for the column groups and the inital `<xsl:for-each>` - there `<xsl:if test="not(position() >2)">` has to be adjusted to `<xsl:if test="not(position() >50)">`. For the next 50 values the `<xsl:if test="position()=$pos+2">`  has to be adjusted to `<xsl:if test="position()=$pos+50">` and so on.

Comment: This is correct, I don't want everything on a single long column,  Iwant in order do down first 50, and after in the next column continues.

Comment: @francesco_irrera It is better to add these requirements - a table with 10 columns, displaying the values ascending in 5 groups of 50 values for two `<td>` in each `<tr>` - as an update to your question instead of editing an answer so your question can be understood more easily. Otherwise people wanting to provide suggestions to your question would also have to read answers and comments to understand the requirement.

Comment: @francesco_irrera I've just updated my answer for an example how to print the values in groups of 50 in a 10 column table.

Comment: I tried your solution and run very well, but I am studynd to improve my personal solution that is similar to yours. Thanks to you and all the member community.